# Jackson: Customizing resolving of ObjectIds (from @JsonIdentityInfo)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

In my Spring WebMVC application, I'm trying to deserialize a list of object references.

Here is what my model field looks like:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Article {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private List<Article> related;
}
```

Whenever I try to deserialize a JSON-Object, I get the following debugging message:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve
>   Object Id [351] (for [simple type, class
>   com.company.package.domain.Article]) -- unresolved
>   forward-reference? (through reference chain:
>   com.company.package.domain.Article["related"])

The object looks like this:

```
{ 
  "id": 123,
  "related": [351]
}
```

I've tried writing my custom deserializer to deal with this, but as the relationship is to an object of the same class, Jackson will try to deserialize the parent object with the custom deserializer as well, which will obviously fail since it's not just an integer......

So is there a way to tell Jackson to use the database to lookup the objects behind the IDs?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.4.0 you can use the "resolver" property of the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        resolver = MyCustomObjectIdResolver.class,
        scope = Article.class,
        property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
private List<Article> related;
```

As you do that, you will most likely be annoyed by https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/524 because of @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true).

This was fixed in 2.4.3 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/17690f355e19cee89967b075fe4a510d780b1d2b

Comment: Tried to edit your post as there is a typo in MyCustomObjectIdResolver.class in code. Your code shows an "n" instead of "m" in Custom.